# Independence of a random variable with respect to a filtration

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-probability, martingales

[Given the mentioned stochastic processes $M_n$, $X_n$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqufN.jpg) I tried to show that $M_n$ is a martingale with respect to the filtration $\mathcal{F_n}$ generated by $M_n$. My proof is dependent on the fact that: $$E[X_k|\mathcal{F_n}] = E[X_k]$$ i.e $X_k$ is independent of $\mathcal{F_n}$.

My question is: is this true, and if so, what is the reasoning?

Comment: This is true if and only if $k>n$ which you can see by showing $\mathcal{F}_n=\sigma(X_i \mid i\leq n)$

Comment: Okay I see. As a follow up question: would $X_{n+1}$ be independent of the ${F}_n=\sigma(M_i \mid i\leq n)$ as a result of$X_n$ being independent?

Comment: @RinorBi yes. Definitely.